# Cannot display order table any longer

Tags: magento-1.9

All of a sudden, I cannot view orders any longer.  Shipments, invoices, credit memos work, but Orders returns an error:

**There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1931180224**

The log says:

2014-11-14T01:32:08+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _items  in \app\design\frontend\default\theme000\template\catalog\product\view.phtml on line 173

and line 173 is:

```
<?php if (count($_items)):?>
```

What could have gone wrong?  I haven't touched the site in weeks, no upgrades, no changes, so I am wondering why is it giving me the error now. Any ideas?

Comment: I dont know why this error has just started. In that template is $_items set ? E.g.$_items = something

Comment: Even if you haven't touched the site, something has still changed be that file based or something in the database.  What have you done to determine why a value is not being set correctly to `$_items`?

Comment: That is not the error you are looking for. Look for `var/report/1931180224`.

Comment: Did you manage to get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a notice that is stopping the script I'm guessing your shop is in developer mode?

Either the server env variable `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` is set in the vhost or .htaccess or `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` is no longer wrapped in an `if` statement.

To resolve this either turn of developer mode or edit the code as follows

```
<?php if (isset($_items) && count($_items)):?>
```